# Docker is not creating database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql, postgresql-9.6

This is code from docker-compose.yml

```
  postgres:
image: postgres:9.6
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: test
  POSTGRES_DATABSE: test
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
  - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

Also on api calls get response that role does not exist

On `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U test` get response `psql: FATAL: role "test" does not exist`

This is working on my computer with nginx but on server, alslo with nginx, this is mistake

Comment: Delete volume and then try

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `POSTGRES_DATABASE` is misspelled. Actually, it should be `POSTGRES_DB`. The Docker readme is at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Also, it looks like you might need to add an initialization script to configure the database with the user and role you are looking to use. See the **Initialization Scripts** section in the readme noted above.

Comment: I have tried and POSTGRES_DATABASE, and POSTGRES_DATABSE, and POSTGRES_DB

Comment: If you missed it the first time, you should clean up any docker volumes before starting your container again. Postgres Docker [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a8613f4cda3e932245f09c4d0f6733462b14b582/docker-entrypoint.sh#L57) has a logic to run the database/user creations only on the first start (if the Postgres files already exist, it skips those steps).